# How do I create a Firestore rule that allows a user to view a document if their userid is an element of an array field of another document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have two collections: `friendships` and `user_locations`.

Every time a user signs up to the app, a `friendships` document whose id is their Firebase Auth userid is created. All documents in `friendships` have one field: `friends`. The `friends` field of `friendships` is an array of the user ids of the document owner's friends.

`user_locations` is a collection containing data on a user's location. Like the `friendships` collection, `user_location` document whose id is the user's userid is created when a user signs up.

I want allow a user's `user_locations` document to be visible to their friends. i.e. User1 should have access to User2's `user_locations` document if their userid is one of the elements of the `friends` field of User2's `friendships` document.

Here is the Firestore rule I created to achieve this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
 
        ...
       
        match /user_locations/{userId} {
            // only a user should have access to do anything to their data except delete
            allow read, write, update, create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
           
            // a user's friends should be able to view their location
            allow read: if request.auth != null  && (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/friendships/$(userId)).data.friends);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to get data from the frontend, I get the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

P.S. When I comment out `&& (request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/friendships/$(userId)).data.friends);` from my Firestore rule, the client is able to fetch data. Also, when I hardcode a user's friendships list in place of `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/friendships/$(userId)).data.friends`, the client is also granted access to the data.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code that you use to read the data and that raises the error?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.